# What are the performance implications of sleeping multiple hours in a Ruby thread?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sleep

I have a class that starts and manages a worker thread.  The thread looks something like this:

```
DELAY = 6 * 60 * 60 # Sleep 6 hours by default

Thread.new do
  do_some_work()

  sleep(DELAY)
end
```

`do_some_work` is not very resource-intensive, taking about 5 seconds to complete on average; but it shouldn't block, and there is a potential for throttling errors if I call it often.

I'm not sure what the implications of sleeping multiple hours in a Ruby thread are.  Should I expect any severe performance penalties using this code?  It's probably worth noting that I can't use a cron job for this task.

Comment: This is usually a sign you need a proper task scheduler rather than some thread that sleeps for an entirely arbitrary amount of time. `cron` is also a good option here.

Comment: `cron` was my first thought; unfortunately, I can't use it in this situation.  I appreciate the answer, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ruby interpreter will be using memory on your system as long as it is running.  So if you are keeping an entire Ruby interpreter process running just so that this thread can wake up every 6 hours and do its thing, that might be bad.  You can use the system monitoring tools of your operating system to see how much memory the process takes.

Other than that, it should be fine to have a thread that sleeps for many hours.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer.